# What tf information does vslam_system need?

Tags: ros, vslam, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
is there anyone that could tell me (or better update the tutorial ;) to
explain precisely what are the tf requirements for vslam_system.

The bag files seems to contain tf information but the wiki does not say
anything about it.

I currently have a bag file containing an image sequence from a calibrated stereo setup.
It would be nice if the tutorial could explain *all* the steps required to switch from the provided sequence to a custom one.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9193/what-tf-information-does-vslam_system-need?/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2011-03-02**:
The bag file from the tutorial works fine. My question would be: how to use my own bag file? The bag provided bag file seems to include tf information. Is it required? What are the frames that are used by vslam? I suppose it would at least need the transformation between the sensor and the main body

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-02-24**:
Hi, are you trying to run with the bag file from this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam_system/Tutorials/RunningVslamOnStereoData ? Or are you trying to run with your own setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're following the tutorial then you'll be using:
`roslaunch vslam_system stereo_vslam.launch`

If you look at the `stereo_vslam.launch` file, it has:

```
<node name="stereo_vslam_node"...
```

This is launching the binary compiled from the source  `vslam_system/src/nodes/stereo_vslam_node.cpp`.  If you check that file, you'll see that it *only* subscribes to these topics:

```
// Synchronize inputs
l_image_sub_.subscribe(it_, "left/image_rect", 1);
l_info_sub_ .subscribe(nh_, "left/camera_info", 1);
r_image_sub_.subscribe(it_, "right/image_rect", 1);
r_info_sub_ .subscribe(nh_, "right/camera_info", 1);
sync_.connectInput(l_image_sub_, l_info_sub_, r_image_sub_, r_info_sub_);
```

So to answer your question, there's no tf inputs needed. You may be able to get it to broadcast odometry data as tf's if you provide the `base_footprint` transform. However that code (in the latest svn) is disabled with an `if (0)`.

---

Originally posted by [rreid](https://answers.ros.org/users/323/rreid/) with karma: 124 on 2011-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rreid](https://answers.ros.org/users/323/rreid/) on 2011-05-10**:
@tom: I've been using pre-recorded image sequences with `vslam_system/src/run_stereo.cpp`.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-04-29**:
@rreid: Have you been able to run VSLAM with your own data? I'm struggling to get VSLAM working using stereo images published by uvc_camera stereo_node. I did topic remappings needed but vslam doesn't work properly: http://answers.ros.org/question/864/vslam_system-not-publishing-visual-odometry